# read with SAxParser

Tags: android

hi everyone I  try to read the information of this direction

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM+BBDb.TO+JNJ+MSFT&f=snd1l1yr

```
    SAXParserFactory factory= SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        SAXParser parser= factory.newSAXParser();
        RssHandler handler= new RssHandler();
        parser.parse(this.getInputStream(), handler);
        return handler.getQuotes();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

but I have this error

not well-formed (invalid token)

if I put this direction http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=yhoo the application works well, but I need read the other direction.

any idea!!!
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The first URL](http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XOM%20BBDb.TO%20JNJ%20MSFT&f=snd1l1yr) contains something like this:

```
"XOM","Exxon Mobil Corpo","6/1/2011",82.03,2.14,11.89
"BBD-B.TO","BOMBARDIER INC., ","6/1/2011",6.95,1.11,16.07
"JNJ","Johnson & Johnson","6/1/2011",66.48,3.25,15.26
"MSFT","Microsoft Corpora","6/1/2011",24.43,2.44,9.94
```

which is [CSV (comma-separated values) formatted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) data.

CSV is not a valid [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) feed format. It's not even XML.